# Dropping rows in pandas .csv [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have pandas-related problem where my rows are not all deleted, only the first 21 rows are deleted. Is there a limit to dropping rows? I need to delete over 600 rows, not 21. Here is my code:

```
i = 0
index = 0
for x in dataAlkuperainen:
    i += 1
    try:
        dataAlkuperainen.drop([int(finalListMatchingID[index])],axis=0,inplace=True)
        print("Dropped idx: " + str(index) + " ID " + str(finalListMatchingID[index]))
        index += 1
    except KeyError as k: 
        #print(e) 
        index += 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
Dropped idx: 0 ID 28
Dropped idx: 1 ID 139
Dropped idx: 2 ID 156
Dropped idx: 4 ID 226
Dropped idx: 5 ID 234
Dropped idx: 6 ID 244
Dropped idx: 7 ID 318
Dropped idx: 8 ID 320
Dropped idx: 9 ID 325
Dropped idx: 10 ID 343
Dropped idx: 11 ID 350
Dropped idx: 13 ID 444
Dropped idx: 14 ID 456
Dropped idx: 15 ID 528
Dropped idx: 16 ID 563
Dropped idx: 17 ID 579
Dropped idx: 18 ID 586
Dropped idx: 19 ID 594
Dropped idx: 20 ID 678
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run a `for` loop to drop a bunch of rows.
Given you have a list of indices you want to drop, simply call the drop method from your dataframe and pass the list of indices to it, e.g.:

`dataframe.drop(index=list_of_indices)`

You can read more about the drop method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. How would I do that in this context? I have list of IDs which work as indexes for rows. How can I delete them.

Comment: Do you mean like this which did not work? 

dataAlkuperainen.drop(index=finalListMatchingID)
print(dataAlkuperainen)

Comment: Yes exactly I meant it that way. This isn't working because finalListMatchingID doesn't contain the indices but the IDs. I've seen you managed to get the `indices` for the wanted rows so good work :D

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick answer. I figured it out.
I wrote the following:

```
rows = dataAlkuperainen.index[[finalListMatchingID]]
dataAlkuperainen.drop(rows, inplace=True)
```

This solved the problem with fewer lines of code.